# How to archive Swift iOS Xcode app with Google Mobile Ads SDK v8?

Tags: ios, swift, admob

The following code loads and presents a rewarded video ad using Google AdMob SDK v8 and Swift iOS. The code works as expected when the app is built, however the following errors occur when trying to ARCHIVE the app in Xcode.

Erros:

1. Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'GADRequest?'
2. Instance member 'load' cannot be used on type 'GADRewardedAd'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?
3. Incorrect argument label in call (have 'fromRootViewController:userDidEarnRewardHandler:', expected 'fromRootViewController:delegate:')
4. Argument type '() -> ()' does not conform to expected type 'GADRewardedAdDelegate'

Does anyone know where the problem lies?

```
import GoogleMobileAds, import SwiftUI

class ViewController: UIViewController, GADFullScreenContentDelegate {

var rewardedAd: GADRewardedAd?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    createAndLoadRewardedAd{ (success) in
        if success {
        }
    }
}


func createAndLoadRewardedAd(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {
    
    let request = GADRequest()
     
    GADRewardedAd.load(withAdUnitID: "AdUnitID-HIDDEN",
                    request: request, completionHandler: { (ad, error) in
                          
         if let error = error {
             print("Rewarded ad failed to load with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
             return
             
         }
        
         self.rewardedAd = ad
         self.rewardedAd?.fullScreenContentDelegate = self
         
         // The Ad was successfully loaded
         completion(true)
    })
}


func showRewardedAd() {

  if let ad = rewardedAd {
      ad.present(fromRootViewController: self,
               userDidEarnRewardHandler: {
                 let reward = ad.adReward
                 // TODO: Reward the user.
          
      })
  } else {
    print("Ad wasn't ready")
  }
}


@IBAction func showRewardedAdButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    showRewardedAd()
} }
```

Comment: This looks like a project linkage issue. How do you add dependencies to your project (cocoapods?)? Does the project build locally with `Release` (and not Debug) configuration?

Comment: @KirilS. The project was set to the Debug configuration. Changing it to the Release configuration does not fix the problem while archiving.

Comment: I didn't say it will. I just asked if Release configuration also fails (just like archiving). And like I said, it has to do with setup of your project. From the info you posted, it's impossible to help with anything.

Comment: @KirilS. Thanks for your response! What information would you need to be able to answer this question?

Comment: Like I asked above: How do you add dependencies to your project (cocoapods? something else?)? did you look at the build log to see if there are any more issues that precede this failure? Did you try an empty clean project? 
It seems the errors you see are side effects of something else: maybe dependency management issue, or maybe side effect of some other error that happens prior to errors you see.